# rand() method not working in c

Tags: c

I am building a basic c program in which you guess a number generated by the computer, I am having a problem in which the number is always 83, my code is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main() {
int number = rand() % 100;
int guesses = 0;
printf("You have 20 guesses to get the number \n");
while(guesses<50){
    int guess;
    scanf("%d", &guess);
    if(guess>50 && number>50){
        printf("Number is greater than 50! \n");
    }
    if(guess>75 && number>75){
        printf("Number is greater than 75! \n");
    }
    if(guess<50 && number<50){
        printf("Number is less than 50! \n");
    }
    if(guess<25 && number<25){
        printf("Number is less than 25! \n");
    }
    if(guess == number){
        printf("Well done you got the number! You guessed %d, it was %d \n", guess, number);
        exit(0);
    }
    guesses+=1;
}
}
```

Comment: See [srand](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/srand)

Comment: Seeding  with srand() is always good.